# Is the UK 'Cycle to Work' scheme worthwhile?

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-deduction

There is a cycle to work scheme my work is offering which works roughly like so:

Change some of your pre-tax salary into vouchers to use to buy a bicycle, and bicycle equipment (helmets, lights etc). This is deducted from your monthly pay as the cost of hiring the bike. At the end of the year, you can buy back the bike with a 12.5% discount off the original price if it is less than £500, or with a 25% discount<sup>1</sup> off the original price if it's more than £500.

I can't think under what circumstances this scheme would be worthwhile following. Where I work the salary is enough that (with careful budgeting) you could afford a £500 bike in a month or two.

Have I understood the scheme correctly, and is it ever cheaper than buying the bike directly?

<sub>1.  *This is my mistake - please see [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/48310/14192) for clarification*</sub>

Comment: Why is this so complicated? Is the intention is to get people to bike to work? By whose initiative, and who is funding them?

Comment: @dotancohen The government?

Comment: Then subsidize the bike, or don't tax it. Governments already have financial tools for encouraging certain behaviour and discouraging others, this seems overly complicated.

Comment: @dotancohen I'm not the government.... try https://www.gov.uk/contact

Comment: I know, the message was meant for them but directed at the internet at large. That is usually how complaining to / about government works!

Comment: Some employers (including mine, a large outsourcing company) just write off the cost of the bike at the end of the year. You have to pay a nominal tax hit to cover the residual cost of the bike, but otherwise it's yours free and gratis.

Answer (score 22):

I administer the scheme for my workplace so I know quite a bit about this.

Firstly, I think you have slightly misunderstood the scheme - the final cost at the end of the year is **12.5% or 25% of the original cost**, rather than **a 12.5% or 25% discount off the original cost**.

This means that if you are a higher rate tax payer then yes it is worth it - if you buy a bike costing £1000 you effectively save 40% of the cost of the bike initially, then pay 25% of the cost of the bike at the end of the scheme, so you have saved 15% of the cost of the bike (£150 in this example). If you are not a higher rate taxpayer I agree the advantages are more marginal, but you are still spreading the cost of the original purchase which is attractive for some people.

Secondly, depending on who your scheme provider is there may be other options at the end of the one-year hire period. Our scheme provider is Cyclescheme and here is the blurb we give to our employees about the end of the scheme:

> During the first year of the scheme, the bike is technically owned by
>   [employer], who hire it out to you. At the end of the initial year’s
>   hire period the ownership of the bike then automatically transfers
>   from [employer] to Cyclescheme, and Cyclescheme will contact you when
>   the year is up to explain the options.
>
> The default and most attractive option is:
>
> 1. You pay Cyclescheme a refundable deposit of 3% or 7% of the original purchase price (3% if original price was below £500, or 7% if
>      original price was above £500). This entitles you to keep using the
>      bike for a further 3 years with no further payments. At the end of
>      this extended use period you can either return the bike to
>      Cyclescheme, who will return your deposit, or you can keep the bike
>      and no further payment is due.
>
> For completeness, the other options:
>
> 2. You return the bike to Cyclescheme, no more money is payable
> 3. You buy the bike from Cyclescheme for a Fair Market Value payment of 18% or 25% of the original purchase price (18% if original price
>      was below £500, or 25% if original price was above £500) so that you
>      own it outright from then on.
>
> Please note that under the HMRC rules for the scheme, neither
>   [employer] nor Cyclescheme are allowed to guarantee the options that
>   are available to you at the end of the hire period. However the
>   options presented above are the currently available options and there
>   is no particular expectation of these changing.
>
> More details about the end of scheme process are available at:
>   http://www.cyclescheme.co.uk/employers/employer-faqs#/getting-a-bike/faqs/what-happens-at-the-end-of-the-hire-period

If your employer is running their own scheme or using a provider other than Cyclescheme, the end-of-scheme details may be different of course, but the details you have given are equivalent to our "option 3" which is less attractive than the "option 1" that we use as default; you could ask whether these other options are available to you with your scheme.

Comment: That is actually much more attractive. I'll re-review the scheme wording later today. Discount vs % of Original price makes a huge difference!

Comment: Make sure you check the price of the bike from other outlets, my impression is that the scheme providers often aren't the cheapest options. You need to compare the final effect on your net pay between the two.

Comment: @Vicky - "This means that if you are a higher rate tax payer then yes it is worth it - if you buy a bike costing £1000 you effectively save 40% of the cost of the bike initially, then pay 25% of the cost of the bike at the end of the scheme, so you have saved 15% of the cost of the bike (£150 in this example)." This doesn't make sense. 1000 minus 40% = 600 * 25% = 150 PAID, not "saved". Please edit for clarity.

Comment: @Chris, sorry I don't understand your point. The bike costs £1000, you are a higher rate tax payer (40%) so paying the £1000 out of your gross salary is equivalent to you paying £600 for the bike. You then pay an additional 25% of the full original price at the end of the scheme (£250) meaning the total you have PAID for the bike is 600 + 250 = 850; you have SAVED £150.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam this is a good point. Cyclescheme partners with local independent outlets only, so not the cheapest in the first place, and you will be very unlikely to get any discount from the shop on a bike you are getting through one of these schemes (the scheme providers get their cut from the bike shop).

Comment: I also have this scheme in my workplace and I wonder if it wouldn't be a better scheme to simply say: "We'll give you back 100 GBP (or whatever amount) once you buy a new bike" instead of wasting everyone's time to read and understand the non-obvious terms and conditions?

Comment: Similar system here in Ireland.  Maths work out on paper, but in practice I was unimpressed.  The 'scheme provider' shop I had to purchase from charged more for the same bike I could find elsewhere.  And, naturally, they didn't sell any used bicycles.  I got a 500eur bicycle and only paid ~250 - but my wife got an equivalent bike for 300eur from another shop.  Add to it the hassle with paperwork and monitoring the deductions from my paycheck were correct, I'm not sure I really saved anything, if you consider the time spent.

Comment: Abruptly switching the % passing the theresold isn't very nice, since it would mean that a £550 bike would be **much cheaper** than a £450 bike, which makes zero sense. It would be **MUCH** better to have a soft theresold, so that regardless of how much is the total cost, the final price is calculated using the first % for the lower _part_ of the price, and the second % for the higher _part_ of the price (if that's above the theresold).

Comment: @Vicky Thatnks for the clarification. Your explanation is much clearer than the original post. It's a very convoluted method for sure. I'm sure the belief of there being inflated original prices at scheme stockists is true also. Lots of good intention, poor execution IMO.

Comment: @Lohoris Except it's more _expensive_ after the threshold, not cheaper.  A  £450 bike is much _cheaper_ than a  £550 one.  You pay 18% of a  £450 bike or 25% of a  £550 one.

Comment: @Joe not according to the OP. And even if that was the case, it would _still_ be a silly boundary.

Comment: This answer and most of the comments made it clear that the OP likely has a misunderstanding... and honestly it's probably a fine boundary.  Sliding scale is more complicated, and at least if UK prices are similar to US prices, this is basically saying "18% of a normal bike, or 25% of a super fancy bike"; $1000 or so is a good upper limit to cost for a "normal" bike here.

Comment: Are there any issues if you leave your job before the year is up?

Comment: @Lohoris I did make a major mistake. I've added a note in the question so people don't make the same mistake.

Comment: As someone from the US, where the word 'scheme' implies at least a bit of fraud, it's fun to read these conversations where the word is thrown around without peril.

Comment: @superluminary, if your contract is known in advance to end before the year hire period is up, you are not entitled to join the scheme. Otherwise, if you leave during the hire period you either return the bike and pay nothing more, or keep it and pay the full balance from your NET salary, i.e. you lose the tax benefit.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor it seems from some of the other comments (e.g. that you have to shop at specific, overpriced bike shops, sorry "shoppes") that this may very well be a US-style "scheme"!

Answer (score 2):

You've already got a good answer on the numbers, so this approaches it from a different direction, the point of view of how to reach a decision.

In practice its worth it if you meet most of the following criteria (and may be worth it if you meet some of them):

- You want a brand new bike, costing <£1000.
- The scheme provider(s) offer a bike you want at a competitive price.
- You are a higher rate taxpayer (greater tax benefit).
- You're going to put the miles in (depreciation, plus it's not yours to sell if you don't get on with it).  This in practice often means a cyclist wanting a new bike, rather than creating new cyclists.
- You've got somewhere to keep it securely (check the Ts&Cs for who insures it and under what exclusions).
- If you have something better to do with the money -- you're effectively borrowing the value of the bike interest-free, so any gains you can make on that value could become part of the equation -- assuming it doesn't just make you spend more.  Prime example: offset mortgage.

Alternatively:

- You don't have the money to just buy a bike -- if you'd be borrowing it this will be cheaper than pretty much any other way.  But then a second hand bike would be more desirable.

*Some* scheme providers have deals like gift vouchers for free kit, improving the benefit slightly as well allowing you to spend the full £1000 limit set by HMRC on the bike itself. I think Halfords did this a few years ago, for example, they sometimes have this sort of offer on for normal buyers as well, but aren't the best place for bike fit (especially road bikes) or non-routine mechanical stuff (IME).

Even for a 40% taxpayer it's perfectly possible to look at it and walk away, especially if you can get the bike you want significantly reduced for being last year's model even though it's new, which is unlikely to happen on the scheme.  Also note that you are supposed to use the bike "mainly" for work/commuting, though they admit upfront that there's no way of checking this.

Comment: unfortunately when I looked at it the scheme was limited in terms of  max price and was useless for London commuters  as you would have to buy a Brompton or folding bike.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it seems just about worthwhile, but in the more general case, some companies  operate the scheme themselves so you don't mess around with vouchers and finding shops that accept them. My company allows us to order a bike for cash from anywhere that will provide a VAT invoice (which should be everywhere).

As the company is buying the bike rather than an individual they may also pass on the VAT saving which makes things more attractive.

As Vicky's answer points out, companies aren't allowed to guarantee that they will sell you the bicycle, but if you can wait longer and trust your employer, the amount you need to pay to buy the bike drops year by year (presumably why cycle scheme only charges 3%/7% after 3 years)